# Не работает событие MouseLeftButtonUp WPF при нажатии на дочерний объект

Tags: c#, wpf, события

Решил написать небольшую программу для отображения примитивов(рисование фигур на канвасе для рисования карты) но столкнулся с проблемой, после реализации отрисовки фигур, решил сделать перетаскивание, чтобы можно было просматривать карту(двигать карту мышкой), использовал события MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp и MouseMove, для этого каждый раз удалял все дочерние объекты из канваса и добавлял новые с измененными координатами, используя смещение зажатой мыши все работает хорошо, до тех пор пока ты не попытаешься перетащить карту нажав на полигон, карта прилипает к мыши и двигается за ней независимо от того отпустил я мышь или нет(почему то не срабатывает событие MouseLeftButtonUp хотя MouseLeftButtonDown работает) единичку с верху использовал для дебага посмотреть проходит ли событие.
Вот XAMl

```
<Window x:Class="GisLab.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GisLab"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">
            <Image x:Name="ToolSelect" MouseDown="Select_MouseDown"/>
            <Image x:Name="ToolPan"  Source="..." MouseDown="Pan_MouseDown"/>
            <Image x:Name="ToolZoomIn"  Source="..." MouseDown="ZoomIn_MouseDown"/>
            <Image x:Name="ToolZoomOut" Source="..." MouseDown="ZoomOut_MouseDown"/>
            <Label x:Name="debug"/>
        </ToolBar>
        <Canvas x:Name="Map" ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightYellow" MouseWheel="Map_MouseWheel" Margin="-2,0,1.6,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="Map_MouseDown" PreviewMouseMove="Map_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="Map_MouseUp" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вход в программу тоже немного изменил чтобы перехватить главное окно

```cs
public partial class App : Application
    {
        App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            App app = new App();
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            Model.Model model = new Model.Model();
            Model.Polyline pl = new Model.Polyline(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0)),1);
            pl.Add(new Point(-500, 50));
            pl.Add(new Point(0, 0));
            pl.Add(new Point(10, 300));
            model.Add(pl);
            Model.Polygon polygon = new Model.Polygon(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0)), 2, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 255)));
            polygon.Add(new Point(600, 400));
            polygon.Add(new Point(-40, -30));
            polygon.Add(new Point(-400, 50));
            model.Add(polygon);
            Presenter presenter = new Presenter(window,model);
            app.Run(window);
        }
    }
```

Код с главного окна

```cs
namespace GisLab
{
public interface IMainForm
    {
        event EventHandler<ToolEventArgs> SelectTool;
        event EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs> MapMouseDown;
        event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> MapMouseMove;
        event EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs> MapMouseUp;
        event EventHandler OnLoadWindow;
        event EventHandler<MouseWheelEventArgs> MapMouseWheel;
        Point GetCenter();
        void DrawPoint(int x, int y);
        void DrawLine(List<Point> points, Brush line_stroke, int line_thickness);
        void DrawPolyLine(List<Point> points, Brush polyline_stroke, int polyline_thickness);
        void DrawPolygon(List<Point> points, Brush polygon_stroke, SolidColorBrush polygon_fill, int polygon_thickness);
        void ClearMap();
        void debugg(string str);
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMainForm
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public event EventHandler OnLoadWindow;
        public event EventHandler<ToolEventArgs> SelectTool;
        public event EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs> MapMouseDown;
        public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> MapMouseMove;
        public event EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs> MapMouseUp;
        public event EventHandler<MouseWheelEventArgs> MapMouseWheel;
        public void debugg(string str)
        {
            debug.Content = str;
        }
        #region проброс событий
        private void Map_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            MapMouseWheel?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnLoadWindow?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        private void Map_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MapMouseDown?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        private void Map_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MapMouseMove?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        private void Map_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MapMouseUp?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        private void Select_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectTool?.Invoke(this, new ToolEventArgs(ToolType.Select));
        }

        private void Pan_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectTool?.Invoke(this, new ToolEventArgs(ToolType.Pan));
        }

        private void ZoomIn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectTool?.Invoke(this, new ToolEventArgs(ToolType.ZoomIn));
        }

        private void ZoomOut_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectTool?.Invoke(this, new ToolEventArgs(ToolType.ZoomOut));
        }
        #endregion
        public Point GetCenter()
        {
            Point point = new Point();
            point.X = Map.ActualWidth / 2;
            point.Y = Map.ActualHeight / 2;
            return point;
        }
        public void DrawLine(List<Point> points, Brush line_stroke, int line_thickness)
        {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.Stroke = line_stroke;
            line.StrokeThickness = line_thickness;
            line.X1 = points[0].X;
            line.X2 = points[1].X;
            line.Y1 = points[0].Y;
            line.Y2 = points[1].Y;
            Map.Children.Add(line);
        }
        public void DrawPolyLine(List<Point> points, Brush polyline_stroke, int polyline_thickness)
        {
            PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();
            foreach (var item in points)
            {
                pc.Add(item);
            }
            Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
            polyline.Points = pc;
            polyline.Stroke = polyline_stroke;
            polyline.StrokeThickness = polyline_thickness;
            Map.Children.Add(polyline);
        }
        public void DrawPolygon(List<Point> points, Brush polygon_stroke, SolidColorBrush polygon_fill, int polygon_thickness)
        {
            PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();
            foreach (var item in points)
            {
                pc.Add(item);
            }
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
            polygon.Points = pc;
            polygon.Stroke = polygon_stroke;
            polygon.Fill = polygon_fill;
            polygon.StrokeThickness = polygon_thickness;
            Map.Children.Add(polygon);
        }
        public void DrawPoint(int x, int y)
        {

        }
        public void ClearMap()
        {
            Map.Children.Clear();
        }


    }
}
}
```

Все обрабатывает класс Presenter в него передаются интерфейсы формы и модели
код презентера

```cs
namespace GisLab
{
    class Presenter
    {
        IMainForm _mainForm;
        Model.IModel _model;
        Point _center;
        Point _offset = new Point(0,0);
        double _scale = 1;
        ToolType _tool = ToolType.Pan;
        bool _isMouseDown = false;
        Point _mousePosition;
        public Presenter(IMainForm mainForm, Model.IModel model)
        {
            _mainForm = mainForm;
            _model = model;
            mainForm.OnLoadWindow += IsWindowLoaded;
            mainForm.SelectTool += IsToolChanged;
            mainForm.MapMouseUp += IsMouseUp;
            mainForm.MapMouseDown += IsMouseDown;
            mainForm.MapMouseMove += OnMouseMove;
            mainForm.MapMouseWheel += OnMouseWheel;
        }

        private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0) _scale *= 1.5;
            else _scale /= 1.5;
            RenderMap();
        }

        private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (_tool!=ToolType.Pan||!_isMouseDown) return;
            _mainForm.debugg("moving");
            double offset_x = e.GetPosition(null).X - _mousePosition.X;
            double offset_y = e.GetPosition(null).Y - _mousePosition.Y;
            _mousePosition.X = e.GetPosition(null).X;
            _mousePosition.Y = e.GetPosition(null).Y;
            _offset.X += offset_x/_scale;
            _offset.Y += offset_y/_scale;
            RenderMap();
        }

        private void IsMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _mousePosition = e.GetPosition(null);
            _isMouseDown = true;
            _mainForm.debugg(_isMouseDown?"1":"0");
        }

        private void IsMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isMouseDown = false;
            _mainForm.debugg(_isMouseDown ? "1" : "0");
        }

        private void IsToolChanged(object sender, ToolEventArgs e)
        {
            _tool = e._toolType;
        }

        private void IsWindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _center = _mainForm.GetCenter();
            RenderMap();
        }
        private List<Point> ScaleCoordinates(List<Point> li)
        {
            List<Point> list = new List<Point>();
            foreach (var item in li)
            {
                list.Add(new Point((item.X  + _offset.X) * _scale + _center.X, (-item.Y + _offset.Y) * _scale + _center.Y));
            }
            return list;
        }
        public void RenderMap()
        {
            _mainForm.ClearMap();
            List<Model.MapObject> list = _model.GetObjectSequence();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                switch (item._ObjectType)
                {
                    case ObjectType.Line:
                        {
                            _mainForm.DrawLine(ScaleCoordinates(item.GetPointList()), item._stroke, item._thickness);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ObjectType.Polyline:
                        {
                            _mainForm.DrawPolyLine(ScaleCoordinates(item.GetPointList()), item._stroke, item._thickness);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ObjectType.Poligon:
                        {
                            _mainForm.DrawPolygon(ScaleCoordinates(item.GetPointList()), item._stroke, item._fill, item._thickness);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ObjectType.Image:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код модели

```cs
namespace GisLab.Model
{
    public interface IModel
    {
        List<MapObject> GetObjectSequence();
        void Add(MapObject mapObject);
        void ClearAll();
        void ClearLow();
        void ClearHigh();
        void ClearMiddle();
        event EventHandler OnModelChange;
    }
    public class Model : IModel
    {
        Layer _low = new Layer();
        Layer _middle = new Layer();
        Layer _high = new Layer();
        public event EventHandler OnModelChange;
        public List<MapObject> GetObjectSequence()
        {
            List<MapObject> list = new List<MapObject>();
            list.AddRange(_low.GetObjectList());
            list.AddRange(_middle.GetObjectList());
            list.AddRange(_high.GetObjectList());
            return list;
        }
        public void Add(MapObject mapObject)
        {
            switch (mapObject._ObjectType)
            {
                case ObjectType.Line:
                    {
                        _middle.Add(mapObject);
                    }
                    break;
                case ObjectType.Polyline:
                    {
                        _middle.Add(mapObject);
                    }
                    break;
                case ObjectType.Poligon:
                    {
                        _low.Add(mapObject);
                    }
                    break;
                case ObjectType.Image:
                    {
                        _high.Add(mapObject);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            OnModelChange?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        public void ClearAll()
        {
            _low.Clear();
            _middle.Clear();
            _high.Clear();
            OnModelChange?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        public void ClearLow()
        {
            _low.Clear();
            OnModelChange?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        public void ClearMiddle()
        {
            _middle.Clear();
            OnModelChange?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        public void ClearHigh()
        {
            _high.Clear();
            OnModelChange?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Код объекта карты

```cs
namespace GisLab.Model
{
    public abstract class MapObject
    {
        public string _description { get; set; }
        public ObjectType _ObjectType { get; protected set; }
        public Brush _stroke { get; set; }
        public int _thickness { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush _fill { get; set; }
        bool _selected = false;
        public abstract List<Point> GetPointList();
        public abstract bool IsIntersects(Point point, double length);
    }
}
```

Код полилинии

```cs
namespace GisLab.Model
{
    public class Polyline : MapObject
    {
        protected List<Point> _pointList = new List<Point>();
        public Polyline(Brush Stroke, int Thickness)
        {
            _stroke = Stroke;
            _thickness = Thickness;
            _ObjectType = ObjectType.Polyline;
        }
        public Polyline(List<Point> point_list,Brush Stroke, int Thickness)
        {
            _stroke = Stroke;
            _thickness = Thickness;
            _ObjectType = ObjectType.Polyline;
            _pointList = point_list;
        }
        public void Add(Point point)
        {
            _pointList.Add(point);
        }
        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _pointList.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            _pointList.Clear();
        }
        public override List<Point> GetPointList()
        {
            return _pointList;
        }
        public override bool IsIntersects(Point point, double length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _pointList.Count()-1; i++)
            {
                double Length = Math.Sqrt((_pointList[i].X - _pointList[i+1].X) * (_pointList[i].X - _pointList[i + 1].X) + (_pointList[i].Y - _pointList[i + 1].Y) * (_pointList[i].Y - _pointList[i + 1].Y));
                if (Math.Sqrt((_pointList[i].X - point.X) * (_pointList[i].X - point.X) + (_pointList[i].Y - point.Y) * (_pointList[i].Y - point.Y)) > Length)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Math.Sqrt((_pointList[i + 1].X - point.X) * (_pointList[i + 1].X - point.X) + (_pointList[i + 1].Y - point.Y) * (_pointList[i + 1].Y - point.Y)) > Length)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                double A = _pointList[i].Y - _pointList[i + 1].Y;
                double B = _pointList[i+1].X - _pointList[i].X;
                double C = _pointList[i].X * _pointList[i + 1].Y - _pointList[i+1].X * _pointList[i].Y;
                if (Math.Abs(A) < 0.001 && Math.Abs(B) < 0.001)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                double distance = Math.Abs(A * point.X + B * point.Y + C) / Math.Sqrt(A * A + B * B);

                if (distance > length)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Код полигона

```cs
namespace GisLab.Model
{
    public class Polygon:Polyline
    {
        public Polygon(Brush Stroke, int Thickness, SolidColorBrush Fill) : base(Stroke, Thickness)
        {
            _ObjectType = ObjectType.Poligon;
            _fill = Fill;
        }
        public Polygon(List<Point> point_list, Brush Stroke, int Thickness, SolidColorBrush Fill) : base(point_list, Stroke, Thickness)
        {
            _ObjectType = ObjectType.Poligon;
            _fill = Fill;
        }
        public override bool IsIntersects(Point point, double length)
        {
             bool c = false;
             for (int i = 0, j = _pointList.Count()-1; i < _pointList.Count(); j = i++)
             {
                if ((((_pointList[i].Y <= point.Y) && (point.Y < _pointList[j].Y)) || ((_pointList[j].Y <= point.Y) && (point.Y < _pointList[i].Y))) &&
                (((_pointList[j].Y - _pointList[i].Y) != 0) && (point.X > ((_pointList[j].X - _pointList[i].X) * (point.Y - _pointList[i].Y) / (_pointList[j].Y - _pointList[i].Y) + _pointList[i].X))))
                c = !c;
             }
             return c;

        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. Пытался использовать событие PrevievMouseLeftButtonUp, где то писали что так перехватываться клик не будет, но и так ничего не работает, пытался вызывать событие не из канваса а из грида и самого окна, но тоже без толку.

Comment: А как и где именно вы ловите событие? Если в XAML, не могли бы вы добавить разметку?

Comment: Всё, добавил xaml

Comment: Не могли бы вы скинуть код обработки события PreviewMouseMove? Возможно там что то происходит. Как минимум у меня на тестовом проекте спокойно проходит событие MouseDown и MouseUp, а так же PreviewMouseMove

Comment: Добавил остатки кода

Comment: Нашел костыль для такого случая, вместо изменения флага означающего нажатую кнопку мыши используя MouseUp и MouseDown при перемещении мыши в событии проверять состояние кнопки мыши e.LeftButton==MouseButtonState.Released